# MultiPart Request RenameFilePolicy

Tags: servlets, request, multipart

I am trying to avoid some naming conflicts in my uploaded files (I used com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest ).

At this moment my constructor looks like this:

```
MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request, uploadPath);
```

I would like to implement the constructor with FileRenamePolicy in order to rename my file with a value taken from a form (something like request.getParameterValue("title");

I think I should use the foloowing constructor? But I don't know how to set the "policy" paramter

```
 MultipartRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                  java.lang.String saveDirectory, 
                  int maxPostSize, 
                  java.lang.String encoding, 
                  FileRenamePolicy policy)
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a custom  `FileRenamePolicy` which gives you the `File` appending the `title` sent along with the request.

**Here is what you are looking for:**

```
 private static class MyTitleRenamePolicy extends FileRenamePolicy {
      java.io.File rename(java.io.File f) {
       return new File(f.getParentFile(), 
            rename.getName() + "_"+ request.getParameter("title"));
      }
  }

 new MultipartRequest(request, saveDirectory, maxPostSize, encoding, 
                        new MyTitleRenamePolicy(request));
```

Comment: since my form is multipart/form-data how could i get `title` by `request.getParameter("title")` it gives error. the only way to get 'title' is to make a multipart object then write `m.getParameter("title")`??
but still its gives error after replacing `request` with `multipartrequest` object

Comment: and there is also one another error in my scenario that multipartrequest rename the existing file in the directory not the file uploaded. plz help??

Comment: FileRenamePolicy is an interface how can u extend it is it possible??